# nodejs why its chaning timezone of date automatically

Tags: node.js

Here is my node.js code

```
var app = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        var start = new Date(parseInt(queryData.start));
        var end = new Date(parseInt(queryData.end));

        console.log(start);
        console.log(end);
        ....
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at 3000');
```

I am requesting url mywebapp:3000/?start=1391230800000&end=1396324800000

On nodejs console I am getting

```
Server running at 3000
Sat Feb 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
Tue Apr 01 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSD)
Invalid Date
Invalid Date
```

Also its looking that console is out putting 4 times, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is not changing timezone. Your operating system does.

> Also its looking that console is out putting 4 times, why is that?

2nd request is for `favicon.ico`, that's what browsers do

Comment: Thanks for explaining.. but how to fix? I want to set time zone like GMT +4 and bypass favicon request

Comment: I would suggest to set your system timezone to UTC and never bother about timezones ever again...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have outdated system, since it assumes that in March the clock will advance 1 hour (MSD stands for Moscow Daylight Time). It's actually not an issue, unless you want yo use result of `toString` directly